# .htaccess force whole site https except some path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https, url-rewriting

I've managed to switch all my website in https through .htaccess with these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
```

Now I have a problem, because some 3rd parties services using POST urls like:

```
http://sub.mydomain.com/agreg/sms/service
```

Are rejected because they are redirected and now GET.

I'd like to disable this "force https" thing on every url with `^/agreg/` scheme. I tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/agreg
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSA]
```

But there are now redirected to http://sub.mydomain.com/app.php

What did I miss here?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

QUESTION:

> I'd like to disable this "force https" thing on every url with
>   ^/agreg/ scheme. I tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/agreg
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSA]
```

> **But there are now redirected to** `http://sub.mydomain.com/app.php`

---

Well, that's a valid result according to the rules.

There is a 2nd rule that redirects everything to `app.php`. This one:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
```

Although the incoming URL `http://sub.mydomain.com/agreg/sms/serviceSo`, for example, is excluded from the 1st rule, it is rewritten in the 2nd rule.

SOLUTION:

Assuming the expected behavior is to exclude any URL that holds the string `agreg` from BOTH rules, it should be something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/agreg        [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/agreg        [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
```

Rewrite Conditions are valid only for the next rule. It is necessary to add the same NOT condition to the last rule block.

Comment: Hi @faa, thanks for your answer! That seems correct at first glance. ^/agreg is not catched by https. But I need it to be catched too by second rule. I'm running Symfony2 framework, and ^/agreg/something is not a real path, but something interpretated by Symfony2 router on app.php.. So, my problem is that I need it to hit app.php, but not rewrite url as app.php Am I clair or not? ;)

Comment: Yes. What do you want to show in the browser's address bar then?

Comment: With your rule, /agreg/whatever stays in bar. But not internally directed to /app.php (which process request). So I have a 404 not found on these url.